# How to set a button macro to automatically go to a specific sheet?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros

I would like to the code for a button that once clicked goes to a named sheet or a specific sheet number.

I have tried a few different things but nothing seems to work. 
Say worksheet named "numbers"

I have tried 
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Workbooks.Worksheets("NUMBERS").Activate

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Workbooks.Worksheets(Sheet1).Activate

and many other, can some please tell me what i am doing wrong

Answer (score 0):

Got it!!

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Sheet1.Activate

Comment: Welcome to Super User! While this is a valid *attempt* to answer the question, it lacks detail and an explanation of how to implement.  Please edit your post to expand it accordingly.

Comment: Or if that's too much to ask (Twisty's comment), just remove the question.